# How can I convert an array of numbers into a whole number?

Tags: ruby

I am working on a procedure that retrieves the numbers from some elements that can be found in a select list. For example from "test element (100)" i am trying to get the number "100".
I used this code to do it, it catches the number between the the two parentheses:

```
            before = Regexp.escape '('
            after = Regexp.escape ')'
            x = "test element (100)"[-5, 5].scan(/#{before}(.*?)#{after}/).flatten
```

This code works and the value for X will be 100. But this "100" is in fact an array.

Does some body know how can I convert array "100" into the integer "100"?

Thank you.

Comment: You can just tack on a `.first` as in `.flatten.first` Probably also need a `.to_i`...

Comment: you don't need the `[-5, 5]` part...

Answer (score 1):

Why not this?

```
x = "test element (100)"[/(?<=\()\d+(?=\))/].to_i # 100
```

Example:

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > "test element (100)"[/(?<=\()\d+(?=\))/].to_i
 => 100
1.9.3-p194 :002 > "test (250) other stuff"[/(?<=\()\d+(?=\))/].to_i
 => 250
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use:

```
"test element (100)"[/\d+/]
```

which returns:

```
"100"
```

If you want the integer value, use:

```
"test element (100)"[/\d+/].to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x.first
```

should give it to you.